# Prevent fetch from getting data when page loads

Tags: javascript

Code Newbie here!
I'm creating a Quote Generator. I fetch my API and managed to sync the button for onclick="get NewQuote" but when I load the page first time, it gives me a quote without me clicking the button. How can I make the function to only run when I click the button and not when the page loads when it opens in the browser?   Thank you!

```
var getNewQuote = document.getElementById('btn');


getNewQuote.addEventListener("click", function() {
    location.reload();
    return false;
});


fetch('http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
        // Work with JSON data here
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById('quote').textContent = data.quote;
        document.getElementById('author').textContent = data.author;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error');
        console.error(error);
        document.getElementById('author').textContent = "Oops, seems like there's an error...Well, you can always grab a real book and find a quote. Sorry! ";
    });
```

Here's my button:

```
 <button type="submit" class="quote-btn" id="btn" onclick="getNewQuote()">NEW QUOTE</button>
```

Comment: So why is the fetch code NOT inside the addEventListener???? Why are you calling reload to fetch?

Comment: Reloading whole page defeats the point of using fetch for dynaimic content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the fetch part inside funtion and call it whenever you want.
e.g

```
function myFetch(){
  fetch('http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('quote').textContent = data.quote;
    document.getElementById('author').textContent = data.author;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error');
    console.error(error);
    document.getElementById('author').textContent = "Oops, seems like there's 
   an error...Well, you can always grab a real book and find a quote. Sorry! 
  ";
  });
 }
```

then `<button type="submit" class="quote-btn" id="btn" onclick="myFetch()">NEW QUOTE</button>`